# Reading file in Windows Metro javascript app

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

Is this the right way to read the content of a file picked by a filepicker? I need to read the image data in order to send it to a webservice in my Windows Metro Javascript App. I use a readFile function with a callback that returns an evt parameter and then use encodeURIComponent(evt.target.result):

```
document.getElementById("btnUpload").onclick = function () {
            var input = document.getElementById("file_input");
            readFile(input.files[0], function(file, evt)
            {
                WinJS.xhr({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "http://servlett.domain.com:8080/Servlet/addImage",
                    headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
                    data: "fk_floor_id=" + currentFloorId + "&map=" + encodeURIComponent(evt.target.result)
                }).then(
                    function (xhr) {
                        var success = xhr.response;
                        }, function (xhr) {
                        var error = xhr.response;
                    }
                );
            });
```

The parameter evt.target.result is retrieved through the following method:

```
function readFile(file, callback) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (evt) {
    if (typeof callback == "function")
        callback(file, evt);
};
reader.readAsText(file);
```

}

where file_input is a input component inside the following form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="file" id="file_input" />
        <button type="button" id="btnUpload">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution is:

```
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
picker.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll([".jpg", ".bmp", ".gif", ".png"]);
picker.pickSingleFileAsync().then(progressResults, displayError);

function progressResults(file) {
    file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.read).done(function (stream) {
     var inputStream = stream.getInputStreamAt(0);
     var reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(inputStream);
     var size = stream.size;
     if (size > 0) {
          reader.loadAsync(size).then(function () {
          var b = reader.readBuffer(size);
          var s = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.encodeToBase64String(b);
                var xhrOptions = {
                    type: 'post',
                    url: "http://servlet.domain.com:8080/Servlet/addImage",
                            headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
                            data: "fk_floor_id=" + currentFloorId + "&map=" + s
                 }
                 WinJS.xhr(xhrOptions);
           });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues here:

1. Reading the content of the file as text and sending to the webservice is not a good idea.
2. using `input type="file"` will not give native look and feel in the app for picking an image.

Instead is good to pick and preview image on the lines of this [msdn walk through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465499.aspx). Along with this, the upload `WinJS.xhr` call will look little different.

There are other requirements that might be relevant in the scenario e.g. showing preview of the uploaded image to the web service. I have to take care of many other requirements for our winjs application when uploading image to the service. [This post](http://blog.programtheeworld.com/2013/11/27/uploading-image-to-the-web-service-in-winjs-application/) might be relevant for you for code listing and thinking about this holistically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it already helped me to understand some more methods. But why is it a bad idea to send the image as a text to the webservice (where the WS stores it as a blob in the DB)? The author of the (second) post uses MSApp.createFileFromStorageFile(file); to create a file and sends it over. But this is an object file inside the metro app, it is no content data that can be stored in the database, or am I wrong here?

Comment: when sending image as text, base64 encoding is required to not lose data. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402329/base64-encoded-image-size) gives data abt base64 disadvantages for storing n sending images. The data will be send as [blob payload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms536736.aspx) by xhr. The web server will have way to read the http request binary  payload. e.g. in nodejs server, binary data is delivered as [Buffer](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Comment: Regards saving to database, pl check your database documentation. sql server supports [blob data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t1k839z(v=vs.80).aspx)