# How to filter file types in input type="file" in WinJS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, winjs, windows-8.1, file-io

I have an Metro app (WinJS) in VS2012 where I am using an input type like this one:

```
<input type = "file" id = "uploadCaptureInputFile"  />
```

and I want to filter the files, for accepting just .png and .jpg how to do that

Comment: this question and [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225629/reading-file-in-windows-metro-javascript-app/20236874#20236874) might also be relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with this:

```
<input type = "file" id = "uploadCaptureInputFile" accept="image/*" />
```