# how to convert an <img> element into blob WinJS in VS2012

Tags: javascript, image, visual-studio-2012, blob, winjs

I have an `<img>` element in my app, but it's required to get a blob element with its contents for sending it via `<form>` element, how to do that??

Comment: this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225629/reading-file-in-windows-metro-javascript-app/20236874#20236874) might be relevant

Comment: What is the src attribute of the img element. Typically, you can get a blob from that same source rather than from the img element itself. Typically you're using either a straight web URI, an in-app URI (ms-appx or ms-appdata), or a canvas, and in all three cases you have other ways of getting to the blob.